# Distribution of Maximum of Geometric random variable

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, order-statistics

Let $X_1, X_2, ... X_n$ be geometric random variables with density $$P(X=x)=pq^{x-1} , x=1,2,3,...$$
What will be the distribution of $Y=\max(X_1, X_2, ..., X_n)?$ Will the distribution of $Y$ be discrete or continuous?

Comment: If this is a homework please add the `self-study` tag. In any case, please indicate where is the difficulty with the question (as Wikipedia provides the answer).

Answer (score 3):

In case this should be a homework problem, I would just give you a hint, not the whole answer.  Focus on the CDF instead of the PDF.

Edit: Further hint: $Y \le k$ iff $X_i \le k$ for all $i$. So the CDF of the the max is simply the products of individual CDFs.

Comment: Thank you very much for the hint. It isn't a homework question but I think I have forgotten a lot.